# Apache does not have write permission on html folder

Tags: php, apache, chmod

I installed `apache`, `MySQL`, `PHP` in CentOS 7. All work well, except `apache` cannot write file in html folder. I found this problem when I used `file_put_contents`. I tried

1. Change `owner` of `/var/www` to `apache:apache`, not work
2. Added `Order allow,deny` `Allow from all` to `<Directory "/var/www/html">` in `httpd.conf`, restart `httpd` service, not work
3. `chmod -R 0777 /var/www/html`, not work

What is wrong with my server? Please help me!

UPDATE1: result of `ls -al /var/www/html`

```
total 40
drwxrwxrwx.  5 apache apache 4096 Sep 23 10:19 .
drwxr-x---.  4 apache apache   31 Sep 18 01:50 ..
drwxrwxrwx. 15 apache apache 4096 Sep 23 08:43 folder1
drwxrwxrwx+ 10 apache apache 4096 Sep 23 10:19 folder2
-rwxrwxrwx.  1 apache apache 1574 Sep  5 08:55 favicon.ico
-rwxrwxrwx.  1 apache apache  603 Sep 22 05:05 .htaccess
-rwxrwxrwx.  1 apache apache 9841 Sep  8 08:34 index.php
drwxrwxrwx.  8 apache apache 4096 Sep 23 08:44 folder3
```

UPDATE 2: apache `error_log` (I changed all IP address) - Edited, change to new error_log, after stop `httpd`, backup error_log, start `httpd`

```
[Thu Sep 24 07:06:47.540295 2015] [core:notice] [pid 14439] SELinux policy enabled; httpd running as context system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0
[Thu Sep 24 07:06:47.541787 2015] [suexec:notice] [pid 14439] AH01232: suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)
[Thu Sep 24 07:06:47.569389 2015] [so:warn] [pid 14439] AH01574: module rewrite_module is already loaded, skipping
[Thu Sep 24 07:06:47.572287 2015] [auth_digest:notice] [pid 14439] AH01757: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Thu Sep 24 07:06:47.573315 2015] [lbmethod_heartbeat:notice] [pid 14439] AH02282: No slotmem from mod_heartmonitor
[Thu Sep 24 07:06:47.600913 2015] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 14439] AH00163: Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS) PHP/5.4.16 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Thu Sep 24 07:06:47.600943 2015] [core:notice] [pid 14439] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND'
```

Comment: Provide `ls -l /var/www/html`, the code, and the error message if you want a valid answer.

Comment: After `chmod 0777`

`drwxrwxrwx. 15 apache apache 4096 Sep 23 08:43 folder1`
`drwxrwxrwx+ 10 apache apache 4096 Sep 23 10:19 folder2`
`-rwxrwxrwx.  1 apache apache 1574 Sep  5 08:55 favicon.ico`
`-rwxrwxrwx.  1 apache apache 9841 Sep  8 08:34 index.php`
`drwxrwxrwx.  8 apache apache 4096 Sep 23 08:44 folder3`

Comment: @blueqn can you post the output of this code? `<?php system("whoami"); die(); ?>`.

Comment: @blueqn Also, can you post the PHP line where you call `put_file_contents()`? Thanks..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thank all guy! I fixed my problem with this guide:

http://blog.lysender.com/2015/07/centos-7-selinux-php-apache-cannot-writeaccess-file-no-matter-what/

I hope it will be helpful.

Comment: The given link is broken. Would have been good to include the answer here.

Comment: For those looking for the broken link content: https://web.archive.org/web/20210514095604/http://blog.lysender.com/2015/07/centos-7-selinux-php-apache-cannot-writeaccess-file-no-matter-what/

Answer (score 1):

Permission issue to the a.txt file

Warning:  file_put_contents(a.txt): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/html/index.php on line 2

Comment: I checked, `SELinux status: enabled`

Comment: Just type the following command on  /var/www/html path and provide the result

ls -lZ

Comment: Thank for your reply. This is the result

Comment: `drwxrwxrwx. apache apache unconfined_u: object_r: httpd_sys_content_t:s0 folder1`
`drwxrwxrwx+ apache apache unconfined_u: object_r: httpd_sys_content_t:s0 folder2`
`-rwxrwxrwx. apache apache unconfined_u: object_r: httpd_sys_content_t:s0 favicon.ico`
`-rwxrwxrwx. apache apache unconfined_u: object_r: httpd_sys_content_t:s0 index.php`
`drwxrwxrwx. apache apache unconfined_u: object_r: httpd_sys_content_t:s0 folder3`

Comment: where have you located the a.txt file ? does it have permissions ?

Comment: I local a.txt in `/var/www/html/folder1/a.txt`, chmod 0777. In case a.txt does not exist, file_put_content will create it.

Comment: have you enabled acl ?
[ACL Tutorial](http://www.en.it.physik.uni-muenchen.de/dienste/internetauftritt/persoenliche/rechtevergabe/index.html)

Comment: did you go through the tutorial i sent ?

Comment: yes, I did. I run 4 command:

`setfacl -m u:apache:rwx tmp
setfacl -m d:u:apache:rwx tmp
setfacl -R -m u:apache:rwx tmp
setfacl -R -m d:u:apache:rwx tmp`

it still not woking

Comment: Hey you should run the command to your folders not to the tmp folder which is in the tutorial, you can check the acl by the command getfacl

Comment: Oh... I am sorry! copy-pass error! the folder in my command is /var/www/html

Comment: The result of `getfacl /var/www/html` as bellow:

`# file: var/www/html
# owner: apache
# group: apache
user::rwx
user:apache:rwx
group::rwx
mask::rwx
other::rwx
default:user::rwx
default:user:apache:rwx
default:group::rwx
default:mask::rwx
default:other::rwx
`

Comment: Run following command and see --> 
sudo chown -R _www:_www var/www/html

Comment: the result is `chown: invalid user: '_www:_www'`

Comment: it should be apache:apache rite ?

Comment: the group and owner is now apache:apache

Comment: so is it working ?
1) stop apache service
2) move the error_log file (backup)
3) start apache servie
4) run your php script
5) send the error log file

Comment: It look like nothing wrong, but the function `file_put_content` throw a warning  `failed to open stream: Permission denied`

Comment: can u send the full error message you get from file_put_content ? do u have any htaccess files inside your folders ?

Comment: The error message: `Message: file_put_contents(a.txt): failed to open stream: Permission denied`

I have a htaccess file. It may be the cause of error?

Comment: I tried removed the htaccess file, and it still error!

Comment: where do u have the htaccess file ? a.txt folder ?

Comment: it is in html folder - a.txt folder. But even if I remove the htaccess file, `file_put_contents` stills error.

Comment: from whr did u remove it ?

Comment: I access via winSCP and delete the htaccess file.

Comment: do u have any virtual host setup ? did u removed from both places ? i mean htaccess ?

Comment: did u remove all htacces files ?

Comment: yes, I checked again, all htaccess are deleted. It is too bad if I must re-install apache service.

Comment: thank you very much! I think it cannot be. I will try to re-install the service.
You are so kind! Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Centos SELinux, to allow write to specific directories to apache user use the following commands. Make sure you change /var/www/html/logs to whatever directory you need to write to.

```
$ chcon -t httpd_sys_rw_content_t /var/www/html/logs/ -R
```

Source: https://www.svnlabs.com/blogs/centos-7-selinux-apache-php-writeaccess-permission/